# PMML: Extract Day of the week

Tags: python, datetime, machine-learning, pmml

How to convert/extract/transform Date Datatype into "Day of the week" i.e. Day Name in PMML* only? Easy to get it done by `pd.to_datetime()` but I need it in sklearn2pmml for pmml pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

PMML provides a [`formatDatetime`](https://dmg.org/pmml/v4-4-1/BuiltinFunctions.html#formatdatetime) built-in function, which can be used for extracting date/time field values from datetime objects. The day-of-week field value can be extracted using the `%A` pattern.

This functionality can be integrated into Scikit-Learn pipelines using the `sklearn2pmml.preprocessing.DateTimeFormatter` transformer step. A relevant example:

```
from pandas import DataFrame
from sklearn_pandas import DataFrameMapper
from sklearn2pmml.decoration import DateDomain
from sklearn2pmml.preprocessing import DateTimeFormatter, ExpressionTransformer

mapper = DataFrameMapper([
    (["datetime"], [DateDomain(), DateTimeFormatter(pattern = "%A"), ExpressionTransformer("X[0].upper()")])
])

X = DataFrame([["2022-07-15"]], columns = ["datetime"])
Xt = mapper.fit_transform(X)
print(Xt)
```

When executed, the above script prints `[['FRIDAY']]`.